# When to go for hashmap and arraylist?

Tags: collections

Please explain above question with example scenario I am confusing which is best.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're happy to see new members here. Before getting any answer, you may read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too broad question, but will try to shorten it:

When you have to get the value based on key (key can be anything) then you go for hashmap. Consider a telephone directory where you go to appropriate name and search for person's name to find his number.

While if you have similar object's and want to store them somehow and later on retrieve it say by index or traverse them one by one then you go for list. So if your task is to find employees older than age 50 yrs, you can just return a list of employees who are older than 50.

Comment: for retrieving and inserting which is best in arraylist and hashmap

Comment: So based on scenario to fetch a value, Map being for the best case will give you O(1), while index based look up in list will give you O(1) too, so it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you to fetch a specific object based on keyword or any identity in list then you have to iterate the list get object and compare with its values

In map you can directly create key value pair..you can pass key and get the value.

ex:

A object user is present which has several properties one of them is user code

Now if you have list of user object then you will fetch one by one user object and compare the code of each user...but in map you can directly store user object with user code as key pass the key and get the desired object

map.get("key");

but if you requirement is not based on key type access better to use list.. example as you to  just display list of items or you have to perform sublisting.